# Page not found (404) in Django view

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am trying to wire up a view based on the Django tutorial (1.8), and am for some reason not getting a basic url to work:

```
Page not found (404)
```

Settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'events',
)
```

In the main folder, I have `these_events/these_events/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^/', include('events.urls')),
]
```

In the events app, I have `these_events/events/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^$", views.search_db, name='search-db')
]
```

`these_events/events/views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def search_db(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello, world")
```

This has me befuddled as I followed the example, and this is the way I remember using Django in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `these_events/these_events/urls.py`

try changing

```
url(r'^/', include('events.urls')),
```

to

```
url(r'', include('events.urls')),
```

Comment: yes, that's correct. Do you know why the `^/` caused the issue? as in the exact thing wrong with my regex

Comment: [You shouldn't have a leading slash in your urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/). Django automatically adds the slash, so your your URL pattern was for `//` instead of `/`. You should still keep the caret to match the beginning of the string - use `r'^'`.